# thermal printer stalls when printing image

Tags: kotlin, bitmap, qr-code, thermal-printer, escpos

I have two Bluetooth thermal printers as well as an integrated device.

One of the printers doesn't support QR codes via [GS ( k .. 49](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=130), so I'm printing by loading a file.bmp into a Bitmap kotlin class and then sending as image via [GS v 0](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=94).

The problem I'm facing is that when I print the QR image the other printer stalls mid-image.

I must restart the printer for it to work properly, otherwise it'll print garbage.

---

The source file has the following characteristics:

- 82x82 pixels
- 2.9x2.9 cm print size (needs to be 3 cm)
- 24 bits per pixel
- 2 colors

It's loaded into a kotlin Bitmap as such:

```
var bfo = BitmapFactory.Options()
bfo.outHeight = 20
bfo.outWidth = 20
bfo.inJustDecodeBounds = false

val fRawBmp = File(qrCodeRawFilePath)
val rawBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fRawBmp.absolutePath, bfo)
```

`.outHeight` and `.outWidth` don't seem to have any effect on dimensions (probably used for screen rendering?). The `rawBmp` object has the following characteristics:

- 82x82 px
- total Bytes: 26896
- bytes per row: 328
- bytes per px: 4

Since the width is too small it must be scaled with:

```
if(inBmp.width < 264) {
    val startTime = System.nanoTime()
    qrBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(inBmp, 264, 264, true)
    val endTime = System.nanoTime()
    val duration = endTime - startTime
    wasScaled = true
}
```

This changes the characteristics to

- 264x264px
- total bytes 278784
- bytes per row 1056
- bytes per px 4

Since the width is a multiple of 8 it doesn't need to be padded.

I then setup the GS v 0 header:

```
val bytesPerLine = ceil((widthInPx.toFloat() / 8f).toDouble()).toInt()
val m  = 0 // 0-3
val xH = bytesPerLine / 256
val xL = bytesPerLine - xH * 256
val yH = heightInPx / 256
val yL = heightInPx - yH * 256
val imageBytes = ByteArray(8 + bytesPerLine * heightInPx)
System.arraycopy(byteArrayOf(0x1D, 0x76, 0x30, m.toByte(), xL.toByte(), xH.toByte(), yL.toByte(), yH.toByte()), 0, imageBytes, 0, 8)
```

I must have 1 bit per pixel or the image will be distorted. I achieve it with this (adapted from [ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter](https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android.git)):

```
var i = 8
for (posY in 0 until heightInPx) {
    var jj = 0
    while (jj < widthInPx) {
        val stringBinary = StringBuilder()
        for (k in 0..7) {
            val posX = jj + k
            if (posX < widthInPx) {
                val color: Int = qrBmp.getPixel(posX, posY)
                val r = color shr 16 and 0xff
                val g = color shr 8 and 0xff
                val b = color and 0xff
                if (r > 160 && g > 160 && b > 160) {
                    stringBinary.append("0")
                } else {
                    stringBinary.append("1")
                }
            } else {
                stringBinary.append("0")
            }
        }
        imageBytes[i++] = stringBinary.toString().toInt(2).toByte()
        jj += 8
    }
}
```

The final parameters are:

- m:  0
- xL: 33 bytes
- xH: 0 bytes
- yL: 8 dots
- yH: 1 dots
- k: 8712
- data: 8720 bytes (8+k)

I then send it fo the [OutputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream) of the Bluetooth socket and the printer chokes on the image.

---

I'm testing with multiple devices with different Android versions, ABIs, Bluetooth versions and architectures - *occasionally* it'll print on one device or another, must it mostly fails.

If using some demo apps from the net, the printer does print images, so I assume I'm doing something wrong.

Perhaps the image is too big for the buffer?

---

**Edit 1**

On a simple test using text1 + image + text2, it'll print text1 and image if i flush the stream; but won't print text2, i.e.:

```
bt.outStream!!.write(byteArrayOf(0x1B, 0x74, 0x02)) // ESC t codepage PC437 USA Standard Europe
bt.outStream?.write("text1\n".toByteArray(Charsets.ISO_8859_1))
br.outStream?.flush()

var bfo = BitmapFactory.Options()
bfo.inJustDecodeBounds = false
val fRawBmp = File(path2file)
val rawBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fRawBmp.absolutePath, bfo)
bt.outStream?.write(bmp2Bytes(rawBmp))
bt.outStream?.flush()

bt.outStream?.write("text2\n\n\n".toByteArray(Charsets.ISO_8859_1))
bt.outStream?.flush()
bt.outStream?.close()
bt.inStream?.close()
bt.socket?.close()
```

The QR code is readable but i must still restart the printer. So I must be overflowing something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem wasn't in the printer buffer, missing ESC/POS command or data size.

I must wait before closing the Bluetooth socket otherwise there may be unsent data.

So,

```
Thread.sleep(400) // 200ms is enough for _most_ devices I tested
bt.outStream?.write("text2\n\n\n".toByteArray(Charsets.ISO_8859_1))
bt.outStream?.flush()
bt.outStream?.close()
bt.inStream?.close()
bt.socket?.close()
```